# Is spruce bark equivalent to pine bark in potting mixes?

Tags: compost, potting-soil

Composted pine bark is a standard ingredient in potting mixes.  Most of the local forestry is spruce.  Is there any reason to not use spruce bark?

I know that generally barks need to be composted at least 90 days, and preferably a year to get rid of volatiles (terpenes?) but I'm not sure of the chemical differences between the two genuses.

So:  Does spruce bark work?